# Is $H/H_0 = HG/H_0G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If I have a quotient group $H/H_0$ and another group $G$ such that $H_0G\unlhd HG$. Is it then true that $H/H_0 = HG/H_0G$?

Comment: So *all* the groups here are embedded as subgroups in another, big group...right?

Comment: yes. are there some conditions under which the statement is true?

Comment: Well, as the answer belows shows, there are certain conditions under which it is *not* true: if $\;H_0\le H\le G\;$ , then $\;H_0G=HG=G\;$ , so $\;H_0G/HG=1\;$ , whereas clearly we don't *have* to have $\;H/H_0=1\;$ For example, every time with the above conditions and $\;H_0\lhd H\;,\;\;H_0\neq H\;$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, take $\{1\}=H_{0} \lt H \lt G$, and put $G$ in your example the whole group $G$. Then you get a contradiction: $H/H_{0}=H=G/G\cong \{1\}$

But ... it is true when for instance $G \cap H\subseteq H_{0}$. Let us prove this. It hinges on the fact that in general $H \cap H_{0}G=H_{0}(H \cap G)$ (*Dedekind's Modular Law*). Then $HG/H_{0}G=H(H_{0}G)/H_{0}G\cong H/(H \cap H_{0}G)=H/H_{0}(H \cap G)=H/H_{0}$, if $G \cap H\subseteq H_{0}$.

Comment: OK, great! You are welcome.